# Matlab image analysis, trying to detect direction of movement

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

i'm trying to solve a problem i'm facing in detecting the direction of movement of an image.

So i have this video which i'm trying to analyze, its composed of a contracting objects (continuaslly shrink and expand) and i'm trying to be able to detect if current frame of move is shrinked or expand !

here is an example of 2 frames 1 the objects there is expanded and other shrinked
[image: contracted]
[image: expanded]

Note: you can't see deference when they are on top of each other, try to save and view one after other on your computer.

So is there a way i can detect the direction of movement in video ? (inward of outward ?)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solve with "optical flow" which has been studied for several decades now.

The classical method is Horn-Schnuck http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method which you can download here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22756-horn-schunck-optical-flow-method . It's fast but not the most accurate way to solve the problem as it tends to blur the regions you are interested in detecting since it minimizes the L2 norm of the gradients. Here's what I got on your images using Horn-Schnuck off the shelf:

[image: The red areas correspond to regions of motion.]

Since your images have lots of edges it's probably worthwhile to try out some more modern algorithms. http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/ might help.

Comment: sorry but i still can not figure out how to return the direction of movement using Optical flow ?

Comment: The output of optical flow will be a vector field tracking where each point goes. What I showed in the photo is just a plot of the norm of the vector field at each point, high values correspond to points that move far. You won't be able to see contraction/expansion from that image, but once you run the actual optical flow algorithms you'll get vectors that correspond to the direction of motion.

Comment: well my main AIM of code is to be able to identify if this frame compared to the one before it IS contracted/expanded or normal. so this mean that i cannt use optical flow

Comment: You're working with these videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9xgDnkkPt0 right? Optical flow will find that motion. If it's contracting then you will see a vector field with arrows pointing inward. If it's an expansion the arrows will point outwards.